# firing find() Query from java in mongoDb getting slower when data size reaches over 5 million

Tags: java, mongodb, performance

I am facing performance issues with my application on doing find() operations in mongoDb from java and when data size is more than 5 million,it's taking lot of time(sometimes thousand of milliseconds for searching a single document).

Any inputs are appreciated. :)

java find query:

```
db.test.find("flag":false, $or:[{"uni.phone":"99********"},{"uni.mail":"abc@test.com"}]
```

Indexes at mongoDb:

```
db.test.createIndex({"flag":-1})
db.test.createIndex({"uni.phone":1})
db.test.createIndex({"uni.mail":1})
```

Mongo Document json:

```
{
    "_id" : "912c2345-f95g-40bf-c871-f6135d3acd879",
    "uni" : {
        "phone" : [
            "99********"
        ],
        "email" : [
            "abc@test.com"
        ]
    },
    "comb" : false,
    "flag" : false,
    "combIds" : null,
    "Histories" : null,
    "creationDate" : "2017-06-14T17:03:44Z"
}
```

`Mongo Stats`: captured here [Mongo sample stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJjJs.png)

Comment: Indexes are on the wrong fields. You want `db.test.createIndex({"uni.phone":1})` and `db.test.createIndex({"uni.mail":1})`. They are nested, so the "path" matters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out....Indexes are:   
db.test.createIndex({"flag":-1})
db.test.createIndex({"uni.phone":1})
db.test.createIndex({"uni.mail":1})

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you using and what type of deployment (standalone, replica set, sharded cluster)? Can you include the results of `explain(true)`?