# Mongo performance is very slow

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

I am facing issue with performance of mongo. Are the index causing performance issue?
Any insights will be appreciated.

thanks :)

Below is the document format:
{
        "_id" : "3bb8d860-7be1-47a9-9d98-7642bd899e21",
        "keys" : {
                "phone" : [
                          "9876543210",
                          "1234567890"
                ],
                "email" : [
                          "abc@test.com",
                          "xyz@test.com"
                ]
        },
        "mergeFlag" : true,
        "decommissionedFlag" : false,
}

Indexes:

```
Below are the indexes i have on my collection:
db.collection.createIndex({"decommissionedFlag" : 1})
db.collection.createIndex({"keys.email":1})
db.collection.createIndex({"keys.phone":1})
```

Comment: What is the reason for creating the index on decommissionedFlag? Do you have any specific query access pattern on this field? Please explain which operation is having performance issue.

Comment: This looks like the same question you posted previously: [firing find() Query from java in mongoDb getting slower when data size reaches over 5 million](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561660/firing-find-query-from-java-in-mongodb-getting-slower-when-data-size-reaches-o). Rather than posting duplicate questions, I'd suggest updating your original question with more details to help make it more answerable.

Comment: Yes, I need this decommissionedFlag index for doing search in mongo.I am doing query in mongo on phone,email and decomissionedFlag fields. Stats are in 1000 for query(my requirement is to reach in 10k query operations),,which is kinda slow.My DB size is 62GB(18GB index size) and it is 64 bits 32 GB RAM machine.

Comment: I am using wired tiger, 3.2 mongoDB version and its a standalone DB setup.